# Закрыть порт 8080 но открыть 80

Tags: nginx, iptables

При запросе на ресурс по порту 80 он проксируется `nginx` на порт 8080.
В итоге ресурс откликается и на порт 80 и на порт 8080.

Как и чем мне закрыть доступность ресурса по порту 8080, но чтобы он был доступен по порту 80?

Comment: Перенастройте сам ресурс чтобы он биндился только на локалхост

Comment: В /etc/hosts прописать чтоли?

Comment: Нет, в настройках самого ресурса

Comment: Можете дать ссылку? Я не пойму как даже загуглить это.

Comment: Из-за того, что вы не рассказали, что такое ресурс вообще, более конкретно ответить не получится :)

Comment: Это Jenkins на порту 8080

Comment: Наверно https://serverfault.com/questions/233951/how-can-i-get-jenkins-to-stop-listening-for-remote-connections

Comment: `google://jenkins+listen+localhost+only`

Comment: сделал как описано вот здесь https://serverfault.com/questions/233951/how-can-i-get-jenkins-to-stop-listening-for-remote-connections . после рестарта jenkins вообще не поднялся

Comment: @MedvedevAlexandr, так добавьте в текст вопроса: что вы изменили, что делаете, что получаете в ответ и в логах (jenkins-а). для изменения вопроса нажмите [edit]

Answer (score 2):

Добрый день.

Всё достаточно просто. Ubuntu 16.04

**В конфиге nginx-а**

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name "доменное_имя";
location / {
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_read_timeout  90;
}
}
```

**В /etc/default/jenkins**

```
HTTP_HOST=127.0.0.1
JENKINS_ARGS="--webroot=/var/cache/$NAME/war --httpPort=$HTTP_PORT
--httpListenAddress=$HTTP_HOST"
```